# Javascript current url

Tags: javascript, url

I am using javascript. How do I get the path of the current URL and assign it to my code?
Here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".share").hideshare({
    link: "current_url",
    position: "top"
  });
});
```

Comment: Use `window.location` to get the current URL.

Comment: window.location.href will give you the current url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get Current URL, you can use:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname; // Returns path only
var url      = window.location.href;     // Returns full URL
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `window.location.href`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".share").hideshare({
    link: window.location.href,
    position: "top"
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with `window.location.href` or `document.URL` object

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".share").hideshare({
    link: window.location.href,
    position: "top"
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like the following should do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".share").hideshare({
    link: location.href
    position: "top"
  });
});
```

The window.location (also can be referenced by `location`) property contains many utility functions related to the current page.

Such as `window.location.hash` for the anchor 
or `window.location.search` for the query string

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `window.location.href` or `window.location.path` expressions if you don't need the full url.

Comment: `window.location.path` don't work on the latest version of Chrome/Firefox - `window.location.pathname` however should work

Answer (score 2):

Use `window.location.href` or `window.location.pathname` expressions if you don't need the full url. I mean

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".share").hideshare({
    link: "window.location.href/window.location.pathname",
    position: "top"
  });
});
```

Comment: `window.location.href/window.location.pathname` what is the difference?

Comment: Are you Blind ? Difference mentioned above the code.

Comment: Sorry. Thank You for your reply.